# How to convert arduino's digital output in terms of frequency

Tags: audio, arduino, android-sensors, arduino-uno

I am using a analog-output sound sensor module where the output of the sensor module is connected to the arduino and can see arduino is doing Ato D conversion and displaying integers from range 0 to 1023.

But I need to calculate the frequency of the sound getting measure from the sensor.

so could you help me, hwo to calculate the frequecy from this Ato D converted values from arduino.

Comment: Do you have the datasheet of the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to to ADC conversions do you? All you need to do is detect a rising edge on the input and then count those. Since your sensor will output low-high-low sequences, and since the Arduino will register HIGH as over a certain voltage, that should be adequate.

This code will measure up to around 200 kHz, from an input connected to digital pin 8 on the board:

```
// Input: Pin D8 

volatile boolean first;
volatile boolean triggered;
volatile unsigned long overflowCount;
volatile unsigned long startTime;
volatile unsigned long finishTime;

// timer overflows (every 65536 counts)
ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect) 
{
  overflowCount++;
}  // end of TIMER1_OVF_vect

ISR (TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
  {
  // grab counter value before it changes any more
  unsigned int timer1CounterValue;
  timer1CounterValue = ICR1;  // see datasheet, page 117 (accessing 16-bit registers)
  unsigned long overflowCopy = overflowCount;

  // if just missed an overflow
  if ((TIFR1 & bit (TOV1)) && timer1CounterValue < 0x7FFF)
    overflowCopy++;

  // wait until we noticed last one
  if (triggered)
    return;

  if (first)
    {
    startTime = (overflowCopy << 16) + timer1CounterValue;
    first = false;
    return;  
    }

  finishTime = (overflowCopy << 16) + timer1CounterValue;
  triggered = true;
  TIMSK1 = 0;    // no more interrupts for now
  }  // end of TIMER1_CAPT_vect

void prepareForInterrupts ()
  {
  noInterrupts ();  // protected code
  first = true;
  triggered = false;  // re-arm for next time
  // reset Timer 1
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;

  TIFR1 = bit (ICF1) | bit (TOV1);  // clear flags so we don't get a bogus interrupt
  TCNT1 = 0;          // Counter to zero
  overflowCount = 0;  // Therefore no overflows yet

  // Timer 1 - counts clock pulses
  TIMSK1 = bit (TOIE1) | bit (ICIE1);   // interrupt on Timer 1 overflow and input capture
  // start Timer 1, no prescaler
  TCCR1B =  bit (CS10) | bit (ICES1);  // plus Input Capture Edge Select (rising on D8)
  interrupts ();
  }  // end of prepareForInterrupts


void setup () 
  {
  Serial.begin(115200);       
  Serial.println("Frequency Counter");
  // set up for interrupts
  prepareForInterrupts ();   
  } // end of setup

void loop () 
  {
  // wait till we have a reading
  if (!triggered)
    return;

  // period is elapsed time
  unsigned long elapsedTime = finishTime - startTime;
  // frequency is inverse of period, adjusted for clock period
  float freq = F_CPU / float (elapsedTime);  // each tick is 62.5 ns at 16 MHz

  Serial.print ("Took: ");
  Serial.print (elapsedTime);
  Serial.print (" counts. ");

  Serial.print ("Frequency: ");
  Serial.print (freq);
  Serial.println (" Hz. ");

  // so we can read it  
  delay (500);

  prepareForInterrupts ();   
}   // end of loop
```

More discussion and information at [Timers and counters](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers).

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested you in the other thread, the best is to

1. filter
2. amplify
3. apply a threshold
4. measure the time between edges

Steps 1, 2, 3 can be performed in software but it is MUCH better to perform them in hardware. The fourth step is what Nick Gammon solution is about... But you have to first make steps 1,2,3 in HW otherwise you will receive a lot of "noisy" readings